# How do I find if a string contains "vbNewLine" or "enter keypress"?

Tags: string, vba, contains

I am currently editing a code in VB Codes in MS Access. How do I find if a String contains "vbNewLine" or "enter keypress" ?

I tried

```
tf = AnforderungVal.contains(vbNewLine)
```

But I always get a "Invalid Identifier" error.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing this special charachter by it's code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: i always used vbcrlf instead of vbnewline. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA doesn't have a `Contains` method. Instead use `Instr` and something like:

```
tf= Instr(AnforderungVal,vbnewline) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by @Doug Glancy but it didn't work exactly how i wanted to. It might have something to do with using VB instead of VBA.

Anyways, if there's anyone out there trying this but in VB instead I solved my problem by using `contains` and instead of `vbnewline` I tried `vbLf` and it worked perfecly, something like this:

```
YourString.Contains(vbLf)
```